# Why are the tile icons in the tile select so small?

Tags: godot

Im using godot 3.5 and im having a issue where the tile icons in the tile select are minuscule. this can be irritating when trying to pick a tile as they are to small to recognize. i have never encountered this issue before.

[heres a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGMQg.png)

I did not really do anything that would cause this to happen but here we are

Answer (score 0):

The tiles appear small because you changed their size with the slider. Use said slider to make them appear big again:

[image: Slider pointed with lazo and red arrow]